# Cursor is not moving in vs code after pressing the left arrow key

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Iam experiencing a problem where the cursor in VS Code is not moving after I press the left arrow key. I have tried restarting VS Code, disabling all extensions, and resetting VS Code settings to default, but the problem persists.

I am using VS Code version 1.84.0 on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: What about other applications like a word processor? Is it possible that your left arrow key is just broken? Do you have another keyboard to try

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.